# how to increase the size of 2d char array element size in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, multidimensional-array

```
char symbol[100][100];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       printf("enter the symbol\n");
       scanf("%s",&symbol[0][i]);   
    }
strncat(&symbol[0][0],"1",1);
```

**output**
for ex:-
in symbol[0][0] i have entered 'a'

```
strncat(&symbol[0][0],"1",1);
```

should give the output as **a1**
buti know the size of symbol[0][0] is 1 byte thats why itsshowing output only **a** 
how to increase the size of symbol[0][0] sothat it can show the desired output **a1**

Comment: `char` will only hold a single character. So symbol[0][0] will only hold a single character. I suspect the "1" is in symbol[0][1]

Comment: can u tell me some other technique to achieve my goal

Comment: Should use %c for characters in the scanf funciton..:)

Comment: @naddiseo u wereright 1 isstored in symbol[0][1]
but tell mesome technique sothati can concatenate a&1

Comment: @AugustusFrancis using %c nt fulfilling my need

Comment: @jonnydepp If you only need two characters per cell, try using `short` instead of `char`

Comment: @jonnydepp here's an example: http://ideone.com/7L7Ec2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
strncat(symbol[0],"1",1);

int main()
{
    int i,n=1;
    char symbol[100][100];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
           printf("enter the symbol\n");
           strcpy(symbol[0],"a");  
        }
    strncat(symbol[0],"1",1);
    printf(symbol[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Make changes as required..:)..

Comment: i have 2d array isit possible(symbol[0]?

Comment: Yep. symbol[0] is the reference to the first row of the 2-D matrix. That is it stores the memory address of first element in the first row of the matrix. Try this and let me know if it works..:)

Comment: ignore my last cmnt its working but its storing a in symbol[0][0] and 1 in symbol[0][1]

Answer (score 0):

`a1` is composed of character `a` and character `1`. So if you'd like to have a matrix for double-characters wide symbol, you can declare a 3D array like

```
char symbol [100][100][2];
```

then

```
scanf("%c%c", &symbol[0][i][0], &symbol[0][i][1]);
```

BTW: Well, a single `element`, or `symbol` you referred, can be composed of elementary element or symbol of internal type of C/C++. So is `a1` in your question a name of variable or the value?

Comment: but i want to store a1 in a single element its a large code
m just posting the small part here only

Comment: a1 is value
like i said i gave input (a) in symbol[0][0] i want output (a1) in symbol[0][0] only